# Is slower hardening self leveling compound available

Tags: self-leveling-concrete

I have a large concrete floor (775 sq. ft.) I need to level.  I did a poor attempt once 10 years ago on another floor and want to do a better job this time.

It seems many products can only be worked/spread for about 5 minutes before setting.  I'm unsure of both my technique and whether I'll have help with mixing.  So it seems it would be good if I could find a product that gives me more wiggle room on spreading.  Are there SLCs that have a somewhat longer workable time, like 10-15 minutes?

Comment: Self-leveling products are really designed for small area repairs. You may want to order up a commercial load of [gyp-crete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gypsum_concrete) instead. I have many years of construction experience and what you're describing sounds like something I'd avoid.

Comment: @isherwood  That's what I'm planning on.  It's mainly the distribute part that's concerning me.  My VERY limited experience from 10 years back seemed to find that it didn't find it's own level as much as I thought.  Could be bad memory or poor mixing or something else though.

Comment: I changed my reply after realizing how big of an area you're working on. An alternative would be to form up smaller sections with barriers so you can work them separately.

Comment: @isherwood  Thank you!  The partitioning makes perfect sense.  I'll need to look more into the gyp-crete option.  That, too, looks promising.

Comment: So you might revise your question to ask instead how to accomplish your goal. See http://xyproblem.info.